# array.forEach() only returning one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, for-loop, axios

In my function I use `array.forEach` to sort through an array however it only returns on element. here's my code:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Fact(props) {
    const width = 18;
    return (
        <div class="card" style={{width: width + 'rem'}}>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Fact number: {props.id}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{props.fact}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

function UserFacts(props) {

    const email = props.email;

    const [fact, setFact] = useState("");
    const [id, setID] = useState("");

    function getFact() {
        axios.get("https://exampleapi/userfacts?email=" + email + "",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
            const array = response.data
            array.forEach(element => setFact(JSON.stringify(element.fact)));
            array.forEach(element => setID(JSON.stringify(element.id)));
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getFact();
      }, []);

    return (
        <Fact id={id} fact={fact} />
    )
}

export default UserFacts;
```

Comment: is `fact` and `id` array ?

Comment: When you call forEach and call setFact and setID methods, you are setting values for each iteration. That means, only last item will be set at the end of iteration. You need different data type.

Comment: ForEach is intended to perform an action against éléments, not to return elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong here:

**Your hooks only store 1 value so the loop will replace that value each iteration.**

I'd recommend making your states arrays like so:

`const [facts, setFacts] = useState([]);`

`const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);`

And then when getting those values just push to the state:

```
axios.get("https://exampleapi/userfacts?email=" + email + "",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
 const array = response.data
 array.forEach(element => facts.push(JSON.stringify(element.fact)));
 array.forEach(element => ids.push(JSON.stringify(element.id)));
});
```

**You are only ever returning 1 fact component, you'll need to loop through your arrays over the component to generate more than 1**

```
return (
   {facts.map((fact, i) => {
      return <Fact id={ids[i]} fact={fact} />
   }}
)
```

I've kept true to your approach but you might want to consider having one state which stores an array of `Fact` objects which would have the `fact` and the `id` together as I feel this generally reads better when looping over the jsx.